# convert nginx conf to apache conf for proxypass

Tags: apache, nginx

I need to convert this nginx conf to apache conf. As i have tried to convert, But failed to get it.

```
upstream apiUpstream {

  # 1. Set your port here
  server 127.0.0.1:8080;
  keepalive 64;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;

  # 2. Set your API domain name here
  server_name yourdomain.com;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; # RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_pass http://apiUpstream/;  
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_read_timeout 240s;
  }

  # 3. SSL certificate set below
  # Here is added a sample certificate format of letsencrypt
  # You are free to remove it and configure yours here
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.com/privkey.pem;
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}
```

To apache conf.

```
  ProxyRequests On
  ProxyPass   http://apiUpstream/ timeout=240
  ProxyPassReverse http://apiUpstream.com
```

But its not working, Help me to make it workable.And I didn't understand whats top upstream conf and how to convert it to apache as well.

Edit :

I am getting this error

```
peerjs.min.js:52 WebSocket connection to 'wss://api.example.com/peer/peerjs?key=peerjs&id=6yqD1MoKzkK&token=kp8g8w6pj2l' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Connection' header is missing
```

And I have tried to change the cpanel conf for the domain like this.

```
<Proxy balancer://apiUpstream/>

 BalancerMember http:// 127.0.0.1:8080;
 keepalive 64;
 ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
</Proxy>

ProxyRequests On
ProxyPass / balancer://apiUpstream/
ProxyPassReverse / balancer://apiUpstream/
```

After saving this I can't restart apache from WHM. its saying like the Balancer member cant be loaded. I don't know how to fix it.

Screenshot
[image]

and exact error message

```
Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/apache2/conf.d/userdata/ssl/2_4/node/api.example.com/proxy_pass.conf: Dec 07 12:03:54 
ip-xx-xx-xxx-xx.ip.secureserver.net restartsrv_httpd[32106]: BalancerMember can not have a balancer name when defined in a location Dec 07 12:03:54
```

Comment: What error do you get...?

Comment: I have updated me question, you can review it again dude.

Comment: `like the Balancer member cant be loaded` This is the error message I wanted. Can you give us the exact error message that Apache gives? It sounds like either you're trying to use an Apache module that isn't enabled, or you have some kind of syntax error in your apache code. Either way, we need the full error that Apache gives you.

Comment: ...From your code snippet alone, there are like, 3 syntax errors, along with the fact that you shouldn't be using `BalancerMember` unless you actually have a load-balancer...

Comment: i have updated my question again with exact error details and things

Comment: Just to understand the architecture: you would like to have an apache server that is listen on port 80 for http and 443 for https those server has domain name yourdomain.com. This server acts as reverse proxy and should proxy everything to apiUpstream with http protocol (not https?). websocket connection to wss://api.example.com it is called by a js in browser, it is unclear if it is a typo on domain name and I didn't undertand if you want a loadbalancer or if it is a try to work

Comment: Actually i am also not clear with the functionality, i bought nodejs based peer video calling app from node.js and i am try to install it on apache, but they also dont know about apache, they given me config for nginx. I wanted to run this app in cpanel. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33325364/simple-reverse-proxy-with-nginx-equivalent-to-apache this question is exactly reverse process. but didnt help me.

Comment: could you try with `ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/` `ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/` `RewriteEngine on` `RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]` `RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} upgrade [NC]` `RewriteRule ^/?(.*) "ws://127.0.0.1:8080/$1" [P,L]`

Comment: thank you my friend @Lety , Unfortunately it gives me "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.example.com/host/signIn' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." There is something that i am missing.

Comment: this means that your software is trying to do an ajax request to a different domain and that domain is not allowed this. If api.example.com is an other host of yours, you should add `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`

Comment: this link could help you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: @Kvvaradha By the way, if you're unsuccessful with the help you get here, you may get a better response on **ServerFault**, not **StackOverflow**. **StackOverflow** is really more for programming questions, while **ServerFault** is more for server questions..... Of course, the people on **StackOverflow** often work with servers, too.

Comment: @Lety i tried this too. didnt help me. still i am facing the same issue.

Comment: @EliezerBerlin , thank you, i will post in serverfault as well. thank you for making me to understand it.

Comment: If the request is protected by authentication try with `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://example.com"` this directive should be added in api.example.com VirtualHost

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need apache with loaded modules:

- mod_proxy
- mod_proxy_http
- mod_proxy_wstunnel (available in httpd 2.4.5 and later) [docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html)

In ubuntu you can enable this with:

```
a2enmod proxy
a2enmod proxy_http
a2enmod proxy_wstunnel
```

You are trying to connect to WebSocket you need to got to websocket of your node app.

Try something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName example.com
      
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  RewriteEngine On
     
  # If header Upgrade: websocket found, proxy to ws
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]  
  RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://localhost:8080/$1 [P,L]  
  
  # If header not found use http
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket [NC]
  RewriteRule /(.*)           http://localhost:8080/$1 [P,L]

  
  # SSL config
  ...
  
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: thank you for trying to help me on it. unfortunately, when i try your code. it gives me 503 error on api.example.com.  I had chance to get similar thing from stackoverflow.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33325364/simple-reverse-proxy-with-nginx-equivalent-to-apache And this is almost exactly reverse one. I tried it. thats also didnt help me.

Comment: 503 error means that underlying server cannot be reached. I have used posted config in apache with play framework app (http + ws) and it worked. I will check it after weekend and update my answer.

Comment: Thank you @Pawel Hawro, I am waiting for a suitable solution. Hoping you guys to make it work.